# Pipeline for text cleaning / processing in python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, jupyter-notebook, text-processing

I am pretty new to the python environment (jupyter notebook), and I am trying to work on a relatively huge text data. I want to process it by applying the following steps and in the same order:

**strip whitespaces,
lower case,
stemming,
remove punctuation but preserve intra-word dashes or hyphens,
remove stopwords,
remove symbols,
Strip whitespaces,**

I was hoping I could get a single function that could perform the task, instead of doing them individually, is there any single library and/or function out there that could help? if not, what could be the simplest way of defining a function to perform them just with one run?

Comment: All these tasks are straightforward and can be done using a combination of NLTK, regex and built-in methods in Python. You can write your own method that gets a chunk of your text data at a time and applies the tasks one after one. If you want something neater, you can create your own pipeline like this tutorial https://nlpforhackers.io/building-a-nlp-pipeline-in-nltk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, it can be done using a combination of multiple libraries in Python. One function that can perform it all could look like this:

```
import nltk
import re
import string
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer # or LancasterStemmer, RegexpStemmer, SnowballStemmer

default_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
default_stopwords = stopwords.words('english') # or any other list of your choice
def clean_text(text, ):

    def tokenize_text(text):
        return [w for s in sent_tokenize(text) for w in word_tokenize(s)]

    def remove_special_characters(text, characters=string.punctuation.replace('-', '')):
        tokens = tokenize_text(text)
        pattern = re.compile('[{}]'.format(re.escape(characters)))
        return ' '.join(filter(None, [pattern.sub('', t) for t in tokens]))

    def stem_text(text, stemmer=default_stemmer):
        tokens = tokenize_text(text)
        return ' '.join([stemmer.stem(t) for t in tokens])

    def remove_stopwords(text, stop_words=default_stopwords):
        tokens = [w for w in tokenize_text(text) if w not in stop_words]
        return ' '.join(tokens)

    text = text.strip(' ') # strip whitespaces
    text = text.lower() # lowercase
    text = stem_text(text) # stemming
    text = remove_special_characters(text) # remove punctuation and symbols
    text = remove_stopwords(text) # remove stopwords
    #text.strip(' ') # strip whitespaces again?

    return text
```

Testing it with (Python2.7 but should work in Python3. as well):

```
text = '  Test text !@$%$(%)^   just words and word-word'
clean_text(text)
```

results in:

```
u'test text word word-word'
```

Comment: Lemme come again:

Thanks Vlad, it definitely worked out, but partially as I was expecting. After performing the task i was expecting it could take out numbers standing alone and  all the punctuation, except intra-word dashes or hyphens. But some were still in there, or that demands me to do that separately if it wont jeopardize the process. for instance a result like this;

 "delet 11â€ “ 103 kb overlap exon 5 supplementari fig 1b onlin use xq28-target"

where "1â€ “ 103 kb" and  "5" are not relevant but "xq28-target" is

Comment: I suggest you to read Regular Expression HOWTO (https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html). It will help you to understand how to use regular expression to remove certain patterns from text. To remove numbers surrounded by word boundaries (whitespace or a non-alphanumeric characters) you use re.sub(r"\b\d\b", '', text).

Comment: what is your expected output after filtering "delet 11â€ “ 103 kb overlap exon 5 supplementari fig 1b onlin use xq28-target"?

Comment: Sure, I think that material will be helpful. I meant filtering ; "1â€ “ 103 kb" and "5" from that line

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use my pipeline creator class for textual data which I completed recently. Find [here](https://github.com/mcandar/TextPipe) in github. `demo_pipe.py` covers pretty much what you want to do.